# How do you find the first string from a list of strings using recursion?

Tags: python, list

I need to create a function that returns the first string of the string list recursively (found from Python comparison tests, e.g. 'agf' < 'bcd').

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, value, rest):
        self.value = value
        self.rest = rest
    def __eq__(self, other):
        return ((type(other) == Node)
          and self.value == other.value
          and self.rest == other.rest
        )
    def __repr__(self):
        return ("Node({!r}, {!r})".format(self.value, self.rest))

# a StrList is one of None or Node(string, StrList)

def first_string(strlist):
    if strlist is None:
       return None
    res = first_string(strlist.rest)
    if strlist.value != res:
       return res
```

Whenever I test the function, the main error I have is that I only return None whenever I pass a node.

Function example:

```
strlist = Node("xyz", Node("Abc", Node("49ers", None)))
self.assertEqual(first_string(strlist),"49ers")
```

Output:

```
None
```

I appreciate it if someone can help me out.

Comment: I think this `!=` must be `==`, no?

Answer (score 0):

```
def first_string(strlist):
    if strlist is None:
       return None
    min_rest = first_string(strlist.rest)
    if min_rest is None or strlist.value < min_rest:
       return strlist.value
    return min_rest
```